# Is there any difference between "triangulate faces (Ctrl + T)" and "triangulate modifier"?

Tags: modeling, modifiers

Is there any difference between "triangulate faces (Ctrl + T)" and "triangulate modifier" ?

Comment: Afaik no except that modifier is procedural like any modifier

Answer (score 1):

Traingulate modifier is non-destructive (it's a modifier) and you can choose which faces to triangulate based on their number of edges (i.e in some case you only want to triangulate ngons but not quads, like after a boolean operation that leave you with a messy mesh a part of your object and you don't want to spend time fixing it)